# combining two files to get % difference in unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have two files that are arranged like this

```
File1.txt
Parameter1  20
Parameter2  30

File2.txt
Parameter1 30
Parameter2 60
```

I want the output file to contain the value of Parameters in File1, Parameters in File2, and % Difference between File1.txt and File2.txt
as given below. I am trying to make an awk/bash script but failed so far to get it right.

```
Output.txt
Parameter1  20 30 50%
Parameter2  30 60 100%
```

Comment: Consider editing your question to show us what you have tried and your current output. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

This should probably do it:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2; next}{print $0, A[$1], (A[$1]/$2-1)*100 "%"}' file2 file1
```

or, if if the first fields of both files are in the same order:

```
awk '{v=$2} getline<f{print $0, v, (v/$2-1)*100 "%"}' f=file1 file2
```

---

For `join` to work the files need to be in sorted order

`paste` could be an alternative if the first fields of both files are in the same order:

Answer (score 2):

If the files are sorted, you could use `join` and `awk`:

```
join file1 file2 | awk 'v=($3-$2)*100/$2 {print $0, v"%"}'
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
Parameter1 20 30 50%
Parameter2 30 60 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution using `awk` is :

```
join file1 file2 | awk '{ print $1" "$2" "$3" "($2 + $3)"%"}'
```